# is it possible to pair/connect multiple wireless HID(s)/(keyboards) in IOS (iPhone/iPad) simultaneously?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, keyboard, bluetooth

I couldn't find anything by doing enough re*searching* with advanced queries.

Bluetooth should support it, but does IOS allow it?

Comment: Do you mean to use simultaneously? Or just whether you can pair multiple keyboards for use at different times?

Comment: Yes, simultaneously. 
after more searches, I just found this "You can pair multiple Bluetooth accessories with your iOS device." 
[Set up and use third-party Bluetooth accessories - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-il/HT204091)
but that's not necessarily a confirming answer, nothing about Keyboards specifically.